# Spark Save Centroids After K-Means Clustering

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cluster-analysis

The following code is a snipped from my Spark K-Means clustering code.
I cluster on a fixed set of attributes but sometimes I cluster on only 2 dimensions sometimes 10. I have difficulties writing the results back to the database - mysql. The following code works only for 2d. How can I parametrize this?

```
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(k).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

// Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors.
//val WSSSE = model.computeCost(dataset)
//println(s"Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = $WSSSE")

var clusterCenters:Seq[(Double,Double)] = Seq()
for(e <- model.clusterCenters){
  clusterCenters = clusterCenters :+ ((e(0)),e(1))
}

import sc.implicits._
var centroidsDF = clusterCenters.toDF()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution is to create a DataFrame with a column that you can not directly save and then define a UDF. Then you can use .withColumn() in a loop to transform the DataFrame. Then drop the original column and save the DataFrame.